# Fixed notation for values with non 0 digits to the left of decimal point or scientific notation in R

Tags: r, format, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I want to transform some number to strings in `R`. I would like numbers which have a non zero digit to the left (or even 1 position to the right) of the decimal point (independently of the sign) be printed with fixed notation, till 2 non-zero decimals, for example:

```
12345.6789 -> 12345.68
1234.56789 -> 1234.57
123.456789 -> 123.46
12.3456789 -> 12.35
1.23456789 -> 1.23
0.123456789 -> 0.12
```

Otherwise, I would like the numbers in scientific notation:

```
0.012345... -> 1.2e-2
0.0012345... -> 1.2e-3
etc.
```

I was trying doing it with `format(x,digits = n)`, `format(x,nsall = n)`, `options(digits = n)`, `options(scipen = n)` and different combinations, but I couldn't get my expected result.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `ifelse(x < 0.1, formatC(x, digits=1, format="e"), formatC(x, digits=2, format="f"))` ?

Comment: Thank you! With the condition being `abs(x) < 0.1` it seems to me it solves my problem.